# How do I get a list of pointers to chars to place their values into a list of chars

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers, memory, runtime-error

Hello I have been constructing a program that will allow me to parse a text file and return a string of char values corresponding to each word in the file. However, I have not been able to extract the chars from a list of type: const char*. Here is my .cpp and .h files:

.cpp file

```
list<char> GetTickers::getTickers(string address){

//fstream myfile (address ,std::ios_base::in);
ifstream fin;
fin.open(address); // open a file
if (!fin.bad())
    exit; // exit if file not found

// read each line of the file
while (!fin.eof())
{
    // read an entire line into memory
    char buf[MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE];
    fin.getline(buf, MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE);

    // parse the line into blank-delimited tokens
    int n = 0; // a for-loop index

    // array to store memory addresses of the tokens in buf
    //const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0

    // parse the line
    token[0] = strtok(buf, DELIMITER); // first token
    if (token[0]) // zero if line is blank
    {
        for (n = 1; n < MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE; n++)
        {
            token[n] = strtok(0, DELIMITER); // subsequent tokens
            if (!token[n]) break; // no more tokens
        }
    }

    // process (print) the tokens
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // n = #of tokens
   //     cout << "Token[" << i << "] = " << token[i] << endl;
   // cout << endl;
       adresses[i]= &token[i];
}

}
```

.h file

```
class GetTickers{

//varialbe
private:
const int MAX_CHARS_PER_LINE = 512;
static const int MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE = 30;
const char* const DELIMITER = " ";
list<char> adresses;
const char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0

public:


//methods
private:
list<char> getTickers(const string addreses);

public:
//constructors
GetTickers();

};
```

Following a build, I get an error, "Type list does not provide a subscript operator" on the last line of the .cpp file.

Does anyone know why this may be the case or how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to have the addresses of the words? Why not just store the words in a `std::vector<std::string>`? Right now, you are storing the address of a local variable (`buf`). As soon as that while() loop is done, those addresses you stored in `token` are invalid.

Comment: It's like the error message says [`list<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) doesn't have a subscript operator (check the linked docs). As @PaulMcKenzie mentioned use a `std::vector<std::string>`. And please format your code properly, next time you post a question here.

Answer (score 0):

The `const` in `const char*` means that the *data will not change*.  Make it `char*` instead:

```
char* token[MAX_TOKENS_PER_LINE] = {}; // initialize to 0
```

or better yet, make it a `std::string`:

```
std::string token;
```

Comment: As an aside - I've always found the syntax here to be backwards thinking. `const char*` refers to a `char*` that points to data that does not change, while `char* const` refers to a pointer that does not change its *pointed to* memory location. I think it's more intuitive to read something like `const char*` as *const char pointer* and `char* const` as *char pointer pointing to constant data* but it's exactly the opposite.

Comment: @sherrellbc, the trick is exactly that: read it backward.  A `char const *` is a pointer to constant char, while a `char * const` is a constant pointer to char.  The syntax `char const` is interchangeable with the more popular `const char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
adresses[i]= &token[i];
```

There are a few problems with this line.

1. `adresses` should be spelt `addresses`.
2. `addresses` is a `std::list`, which doesn't have `operator[]`. This is to make it clear that `std::list` doesn't provide constant time random access. Instead, you have to get an iterator with `begin` and move it along to the appropriate element:

   ```
   std::list<char>::iterator it = addresses.begin();
   std::advance(it, i);
   ```

   Now `it` points at the `i`th element. If you're doing this often, you're probably using the wrong type.
3. Since `token` is an array of `const char*`, `&token[i]` gives you a `const char**`. You can't then assign that to an element of your list, where each element is a `char`. Exactly what you're trying to do there, I'm not sure. Perhaps you actually want `addresses` to be a `std::list<const char*>`?

Another problem is that you're doing file streaming badly. The `!fin.eof()` condition cannot preemptively tell you that you are going to hit the end of the file. What you'll find is that the `getline` that removes the last line will reach the final `\n` (that text files end with) and then stop. It doesn't actually try to read the end of the file. In the next iteration, `!fin.eof()` will pass, but there will be nothing more to read. Uh oh.

Overall, there's lots of problems with this, and it would be a hell of a lot easier if you used `std::string`s instead. I would suggest that both `tokens` and `addresses` could be `std::vector<std::string>`s.